Unable to find valid certification path to requested target error on IntelliJ IDEA
Although I can connect to a MongoDB database on a remote server using MongoDB Compass, when I try to connect using the same URI in IntelliJ IDEA, I get the following error:

... sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

I have a look at and tried workarounds on the following threads, but none of them worked:

Unable to find valid certification path to requested target - error even after cert imported
unable to find valid certification path to requested target(sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: )

I had already imported necessary certificate files before using the following command:
sudo /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-21.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/keytool -importcert -file /<certificate_file_name>.pem 
-keystore /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-21.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts -alias "<certificate_alias>" -storepass changeit -noprompt

I also added this certificate via Tools > Server Certificates on IntelliJ IDEA as suggested on this question, and try to run the app by passing some VM options pointing to the certificate, but still getting the same error. The problem seems to be related to IntelliJ as I am able to connect using the same URI via Compass. Is there any other thing that I should check?

Maybe check to make sure that's the JDK/JRE that's being used to run the code that is getting the error. It's tricky keeping different JDKs around for testing purposes and trying to keep track of them.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk Good point, thanks. I also thought this possibility and also checked that before opening the thread. But it is exactly using the same jdk location when I checked via Project Structure > Project > SDK menu (/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-21.jdk/Contents/Home). May it be related to Mac or is there anything that I should try e.g. truststore part? I also added the certificate location as truststore but nothing changed.

If you run your Java code outside the IDE, in the terminal via java command, will it have the same issue? Why do you think that it's IntelliJ IDEA problem and not Java problem?

@CrazyCoder You are right, it seems to. be Java problem. Is there anything that I should check or should reinstall the related jdk again? Actually I also checked if there are multiple installation (one was installed via IntelliJ from Amazon Corretto version but uninstalled it after installing the one from Oracle site).

Double-check you imported the correct certificates into the JVM and exactly this JVM runs your code. You can add -Djavax.net.debug=ssl VM option to get more details in the output which can help to find the issue with the certificate.

@CrazyCoder I remove all java versions using command line and verify there is no folder reinstalled Java (Amazon Corretto 21.0.4) using IntelliJ. After setting JAVA_HOME and using -Djavax.net.debug=ssl, I tried to run the app again but still getting the same errors: Fatal (CERTIFICATE_UNKNOWN): PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target. Do you have any idea if the problem may cause remote server or completely related to Certificale or Java installed on my PC?

You need to get the debug logging in the terminal to see more details. It's likely the issue with the Java certificates on your machine.

May also be related to another issue on the server in case some error messages are generic rather than giving clear info about the root cause of the problem? Because I tried everything and also other developers from my team get such errors.

SSL debug output will show what cert is received from the server and why your chain cannot validate it.

@CrazyCoder Rechecked all the logs again, but unfortunately nothing new except from repeating the same certificate errors on the log. It is not clear the root cause of the problem, but as far as I understood, it may also be related to server side rather than client side. Am I wrong?

With -Djavax.net.debug=ssl you should have very detailed logs. Probably your logging configuration hides them. It's both client and server problem. Client must have the CA for the self-signed certificate used by the server. Either install a new trusted certificate on the server that is not self-signed, or install the CA on the client that matches the one used by the server.

@CrazyCoder+ no, since j11 in 2018 (and the backport to 8u261 soon after) specifying only javax.net.debug=ssl gets you almost no logs; you must add appropriate subcategories like in this case javax.net.debug=ssl:handshake:trustmanager

@dave_thompson_085 Thanks, what are the other useful options? Or is there any page for full config?

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/security/java-secure-socket-extension-jsse-reference-guide.html#GUID-31B7E142-B874-46E9-8DD0-4E18EC0EB2CF
